# git add remove all white spaces in readme.md file

Tags: git

I have a read me file in my project with some white spaces at the end of each line.
the problem is when I want to add changes to git, git automatically remove all the white spaces from the end of each line.
I know it's a good feature for the code but in the readme.md file I have to have those white spaces so how can I prevent this?

Comment: git doesn't modify the tracked files. How are you executing the `git add`? Are you using a GUI?

Comment: I'm using git bash with " git add Readme.md" command

Comment: it strange for me too, I never had this problem until now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at your IDE instead of git. git doesn't alter files like this, but several editor do remove white space automatically.